# Data isn't being saved in the object when app is killed

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a list where users can picked favorite items and then toggle a filter.  I'm essentially following the apple [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input).  However, when I kill the app the favorite isn't being retained.

Looking at the debugger I can see the object being updated.

After adding favorite:

`User week picked: Week 1, isfavorite: true, showfav Toggle: false`

```
0 Week(id: 27BECDEE-B762-4B9B-8948-22B12923422D, title: "Week 1", text: "SFF v2.0", image: "SoFuckingFit2.0_(week_1)", week: 2, show: false, isFavorite: true)
```

In both cases `isFavorite` is `true`.

Here's the button and where I included the save function.

```
                Button(action: {
                     self.userData.week[self.favoriteIndex]
                         .isFavorite.toggle()
                    print(self.favoriteIndex, self.weeks)
                     self.userData.save()
                    print(self.userData.save())
                 }){
                     if self.userData.week[self.favoriteIndex]
                     .isFavorite{
                         Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                             .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                     } else {
                         Image(systemName: "star")
                             .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: That normal, because each time app start, your app load model from json file, and when you update isFavorite, you only update to your model, not update to json file, so when you start app again, your json file is the same with before, nothing change

Comment: Use CoreData, UserDefaults, or write the data back to your JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the JSON file is static and never changes.

1. Data created from the JSON file and JSON file doesn't relate anymore
2. In a moment when you are created objects from a file, you have objects that exist only in your app memory, and will it will be removed after the app off.
3. File doesn't know anyting about the objects created from him.
4. If you want to save data changed with objects that were created from static JSON than you need to work with Core Data, Realm, (UserDefaults maybe), Firebase, or another type of local or remote database.

Comment: Thank you!  This makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 0):

you have to write data to file when changed and load from file